# Create new smaller "sub" DataFrameS based on groupby made on "root" Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like this:

```
Index        Amount    Currency
01.01.2018   25.0      EUR
01.01.2018   43.5      GBP
01.01.2018   463.0     PLN
02.01.2018   32.0      EUR
02.01.2018   12.5      GBP
02.01.2018   123.0     PLN
03.01.2018   10.0      PLN
03.01.2018   15.0      USD
```

I'd like to create a a function that will split this dataframe in sub-dataframes (stored in different variables) grouped by Currency. Need for ex. a variable (type Dataframe) which has only EUR currency, one for GBP currency, one for PLN currency and one for USD.

So I'd like to have an output like this:

For EUR:

```
Index        Amount    Currency
01.01.2018   25.0      EUR
02.01.2018   32.0      EUR
```

For GBP:

```
Index        Amount    Currency
01.01.2018   43.5      GBP
02.01.2018   12.5      GBP
```

For PLN:

```
Index        Amount    Currency
01.01.2018   463.0     PLN
02.01.2018   123.0     PLN
03.01.2018   10.0      PLN
```

For USD:

```
Index        Amount    Currency
03.01.2018   15.0      USD
```

Main problem is that I'm searching for a clean line of code to do it. Of course could play with some for's and if's but my goal is to achive a clen code.

PS.

Is it possible to do it without declaring currency variables?
I'd like to avoid declaring 40 variables for each currency. Because this example is simplified and in reality df has a large number of currencies and they are not ordered in any way, and not every day has all currencies.
Of course this PS is just an optimization to my question so if it's not possible not matter.

Comment: #INDEX is sorted by date so it's not a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), build a `tuple` from the returned `key`/`value` pairs and build a dictionary:

```
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby('Currency')))
```

You can acces the different elements using the different values in the `Currency` field (now `keys` of the dictionary):

```
print(dfs['EUR'])

        Index  Amount Currency
0  01.01.2018    25.0      EUR
3  02.01.2018    32.0      EUR

print(dfs['USD'])

        Index  Amount Currency
7  03.01.2018    15.0      USD
```

Answer (score 2):

A dictionary comprehension would be the answer here:

```
d = {a: b for a, b in df.groupby('Currency')}
```